# Keycloak: Redirect base url to another realm

Tags: keycloak

when I run keycloak, http://localhost:8080 gets redirected to admin console of master realm by default

http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/master/console

I would like to make a change so that base url http://localhost:8080, will get redirect to my custom realm which i created. For example: http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/myrealm/console

Is there any way to achieve this?

regards,

Venky

Comment: why do you want to do that? whats your business case?

Comment: I have created separate realm for business users. However, if someone hits the base url for example: https://my.loginkeycloak.com they will see master realm. They wont be able to login to master realm but this can be confusing. Hence i want this base url to redirect to custom realm

Comment: @Venky How is your setup? standalone keycloak?,  docker, kubernetes?

Comment: Its docker and hosted on azure webapps

Comment: We did a workaroubd <script type="text/javascript">
       window.location.href = "/auth/realms/myrealm/account"
</script>